How to Separate Login Systems for Two User Types (Student and Teacher) in ASP.NET Core Identity?
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Identity project where I have two distinct types of users: Students and Teachers. The requirement is as follows:

Student accounts can only log in to the Student site.
Teacher accounts can only log in to the Teacher site.
A Student account should not be able to log into the Teacher site, and vice versa. It can't even found the username.

It is something like 2 login systems.
Code ER
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{

}

public class Student: ApplicationUser
{
   
}

public class Teacher: ApplicationUser
{

}

public class WorkNextDbContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public WorkNextDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}

Currently, I am using ASP.NET Core Identity, which generates both user types in the same aspnetusers table. This is causing an issue where usernames are duplicated between the two user types. I don't think roles are appropriate in this scenario since these are two completely different user types with distinct login systems.
aspnetusers Table



Id
Discriminator
Username




1
Student
Ali


2
Teacher
Bob


3
Student
Bob -Error, duplicate username, username must be unique, but identity core generate two type of user in 1 table



How can I set up two separate login systems while preventing these user types from overlapping in the same aspnetusers table and causing username conflicts? Is there a way to keep the Student and Teacher accounts entirely separate in the database or another workaround that aligns with Core Identity best practices?

It's just a "logical" separation. For logging in, all that is needed is a "are you a student?" and a user id to progress to the password page; where from there on, everything can look the same: schedules; class rooms; teacher contact # (filtered based on conext). "Student teachers" included. Using the "academic entity" (party) data model.

If you must have usernames like Bob or Ali then the most common (if ugly) practice I see in other companies and organizations is to append numbers to the name if another Bob or Ali is registered - Bob2, Ali2. You have to deal with this anyway no matter what you do because two students can be named Bob.

Based on my opinion it is better to use different table, login and identity options for both type which is student and teacher. For that you might need to modify the code little bit. even keep separate Authorization Policies.
 public class StudentDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Student>
   {
       public StudentDbContext(DbContextOptions<StudentDbContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
       }
   }

   public class TeacherDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Teacher>
   {
       public TeacherDbContext(DbContextOptions<TeacherDbContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
       }
   }

Set the user type column in the tables to show if the user is teacher or student. And to avoid the username conflict issue use the email id which will be unique for the login or create unique username by using custom code.
